# Converting a function into a ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically I want to write a function that works in the typical ggplot fashion where you simply "add" it on using the `+` operator.  What I have right now is the following:

In order to make this reproducible, I saved the following image as a png to my working directory and use mtcars for the plot data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chevypnglogo.png

```
library(png)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

logo <- readPNG(
  source = 'Chevypnglogo.png'
)
logo_grob <- rasterGrob(logo, interpolate = TRUE)
add_logo <- function(g, logo) {
  y.range <- ggplot_build(g)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range
  y.space <- (y.range[2] - y.range[1]) / 100
  height <- (y.range[2] - y.range[1]) / 10

  x.range <- ggplot_build(g)$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.range
  x.space <- (x.range[2] - x.range[1]) / 100
  width <- (x.range[2] - x.range[1]) / 10

  g <- g + annotation_custom(
    logo, 
    xmin = x.range[1] + x.space, xmax = x.range[1] + width,
    ymin = y.range[2] - height, ymax = y.range[2] - y.space
  )
}

test.plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()
test.plot <- add_logo(test.plot, logo_grob)
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is:

```
test.plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  add_logo(logo_grob)
```

Does anybody know how to alter my code to make this possible?

Comment: Just to note, you have the image as a different format than in your code. You have a `jpg` on the link and `png` in the code. Also, could you include the libraries that you are using so that anyone can reproduce your code?

Comment: Ok, I'll see if i can find a png.  For some reason custom saving as a png doesn't work in my code.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. If you need the ggplot2 calculated ranges/etc to do the plot you'll need to write this as a `Geom` and that'll be much easier in the dev version of ggplot2 on github.

Comment: I must misunderstand the question as well, as I thought the solution was to push the ggpolt methods the other way into a function that also calls add_logo.

Comment: So do I need to download the dev version of ggplot2 or is there a way to do it with the CRAN version?

Answer (score 0):

```
#How about:

#Test data
logo <- readPNG(source = 'Chevypnglogo.png')
logo_grob <- rasterGrob(logo, interpolate=T)

#The function
add_logo <- function(g, logo) {

  y.range  <- ggplot_build(g)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range
  y.space  <- (y.range[2] - y.range[1]) / 100
  height   <- (y.range[2] - y.range[1]) / 10

  x.range <- ggplot_build(g)$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.range
  x.space <- (x.range[2] - x.range[1]) / 100
  width <- (x.range[2] - x.range[1]) / 10

  #Create annotation and wrap it in list()
  my_anot <- list(annotation_custom(logo, 
                  xmin = x.range[1] + x.space, xmax = x.range[1] + width,
                  ymin = y.range[2] - height, ymax = y.range[2] - y.space))
  return(my_anot)
}

#Test
test.plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
test.plot <- test.plot + add_logo(g=test.plot, logo_grob)
```

Comment: This might work in the way that you have it set up but it still needs to make two assignments.  I was hoping for a solution that only assigns test.plot once.